# Pandas Styler dynamically merge cells with rowspan and display?

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Had a look around and haven't found anything specific. I have a Pandas dataframe which I'm converting to html with a Styler object and the render() method. I'm looking for a way to merge groups of cells that have the same date to present the data in a more readable format to different weeks from each other.

```
Input:
+-------------------+-----------------+
| Date   Weekending | Action          |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 27/08/2021        | Increase Output |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 27/08/2021        | Decrease Output |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 3/09/2021         | Make change     |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 3/09/2021         | Go for a hike   |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 3/09/2021         | Bake a cake     |
+-------------------+-----------------+

Desired Output:
+-------------------+-----------------+
| Date   Weekending | Action          |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 27/08/2021        | Increase Output |
|                   +-----------------+
|                   | Decrease Output |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 3/09/2021         | Make change     |
|                   +-----------------+
|                   | Go for a hike   |
|                   +-----------------+
|                   | Bake a cake     |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

My theory was to create a function to take the column and apply formatting to make the first row span the length of matching rows and then set the subsequent rows display value to false, but I can't quite figure out how to accomplish this.

Ideally this should be done with Styler I think .apply() but the data lives in a temporary dataframe so working on the data that way is an option

Comment: This is propably what you are looking for [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: just set the index to be the `Date Weekending` column and then `sort_index` and `Styler` will be default merge index cells that are the same.